# Why Validation Message didn't work correctly with Upload control in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, razor, upload, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a form for upload images in asp.net mvc 5 .

Every thing is OK , but there is a problem with `Validation Error Message`. If I select image in upload control or not  ,   My webApplication always give me alert message `error happened , your data is not valid` . 
but when I delete `[Required(ErrorMessage = "select image plz")]` from `MainGoodMetaData.cs` it works fine !

Could any one help me please ? Thanks a lot

MainGoodMetaData.cs

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "select image plz")]
[DisplayName("good image")]
[Display(Name = "good image")]
[DataType(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType.ImageUrl)]
public string GoodImage { get; set; }
```

AddMainGood.cshtml

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.Upload("UploadImage")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GoodImage)
    </div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GoodImage, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
  </div>
```

Admin controller

```
 [HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddMainGood(MainGood maingood, HttpPostedFileBase UploadImage)
{
    MainGoodRepositories blMainGood = new MainGoodRepositories();
    string path2 = "";
    var fileName2 = "";
    var rondom2 = "";
    if (UploadImage != null)
    {
        fileName2 = Path.GetFileName(UploadImage.FileName);
        string pic = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(UploadImage.FileName);
        rondom2= Guid.NewGuid() + fileName2;
        path2 = System.IO.Path.Combine(
                              Server.MapPath("~/Images/MainGoods"), rondom2);

        maingood.GoodImage = rondom2;
    }
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        UploadImage.SaveAs(path2);
        maingood.GoodImage = rondom2;
        if (blMainGood.Add(maingood))
        {
            return JavaScript("alert('added');");
        }
        else
        {
            return JavaScript("alert('didn't add');");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return JavaScript("alert('error happened , your data is not valid');");
    }
}
```

UploadHelper.cs

```
 public static class UploadHelper
 {
 public static MvcHtmlString Upload(this HtmlHelper helper, string name, object htmlAttributes = null)
 {

TagBuilder input = new TagBuilder("input");
input.Attributes.Add("type", "file");
input.Attributes.Add("id", helper.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(name));
input.Attributes.Add("name", helper.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(name));

 if (htmlAttributes != null)
 {
    var attributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
    input.MergeAttributes(attributes);
 }

return new MvcHtmlString(input.ToString());
}

 public static MvcHtmlString UploadFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, object htmlAttributes = null)
 {

 var data = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData);
 TagBuilder input = new TagBuilder("input");
 input.Attributes.Add("type", "file");
 input.Attributes.Add("id", helper.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression)));
 input.Attributes.Add("name", helper.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression)));

if (htmlAttributes != null)
{
    var attributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
    input.MergeAttributes(attributes);
}

return new MvcHtmlString(input.ToString());
</div>
```

Comment: Look at this link http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/aX9D090113-File-upload-with-strongly-typed-view-and-model-validation.html

Comment: this one also http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1142/asp-net-mvc-upload-file-with-record-validation-step-6

Comment: Thank you , it seems very hard because I'm not good in jquery :( . By the way , Thank you @FrebinFrancis

Comment: i think then you can go for the second link. needs less jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of ways for validating a file input both server side and client side, it depends on the situation you're working on. for example, if you want a complex validation on the server side you can create a custom validation attribute. But if you want just a simple required file input using client side validation you should change your model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Select a file")]
public HttpPostedFileBase GoodImage { get; set; }
```

As you can see, I the `GoodImage` property to `HttpPostedFileBase`, then inside your view we just simply add required validation manually:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input type="file" data-val="true" data-val-required="please select a file" name="GoodImage" />
        @Html.ValidationMessage("file")
    </div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GoodImage, new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Send"/>
```

And your action method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddMainGood(MainGood model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }
        string path2 = "";
        var fileName2 = "";
        var rondom2 = "";
        fileName2 = Path.GetFileName(model.GoodImage.FileName);
        string pic = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(model.GoodImage.FileName);
        rondom2 = Guid.NewGuid() + fileName2;
        path2 = System.IO.Path.Combine(
                              Server.MapPath("~/Images/MainGoods"), rondom2);
        // other code
    }
```

Comment: Sorry , I don't understand what's the 'model' ?!

Comment: Sorry, It's the parameter of your action method, I updated the answer ;)